# Cakephp will not reset model to save

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am having issues with cakephp. I have a database table that has a debit and credit column. Below, I try to deduct money from the first users account and save the record. If the save is succesful, it changes the same array and changes the owner id to the id of the user the money is going to and makes the debit a credit. THe problem is this

incorrect

```
user_id payment_to_id credit debit
1       2             0.00   3.00
1       2             3.00   0.00
```

below is how it should show. Since user_id 2 is recieving the money, the payment_to_id is left null. But its not working like this. its working like what is showing above which is incorrect. I am using the create() method to create a new record but it doesnt work. what am i doing wrong

```
user_id payment_to_id credit debit
1       2             0.00   3.00
2       null          3.00   0.00
```

Below is the code

```
    function advanced_transfer($data = array()) {
        if(!empty($data)) {
            //I store the original credit in a variable called credit
            $credit = $data['PaymentTransaction']['credit'];
            //since I have credit stored, a zero it out so it wont save
            $data['PaymentTransaction']['credit'] = 0;
            //then I first set up a debit transaction
            $data['PaymentTransaction']['debit'] = $credit;
            //I am storing both the account owner and payment to id's
            $accountOwnerId = $data['PaymentTransaction']['user_id'];
            $paymentToId = $data['PaymentTransaction']['payment_to_id'];
            $this->create();//new record
            if($this->save($data, false)) {//save
                $data['PaymentTransaction']['user_id'] = $paymentToId;//I set the owner to the payment to user
                $data['PaymentTransaction']['payment_to_id'] = null;//I null out payment to cause the user is recieving
                $data['PaymentTransaction']['credit'] = $credit;//I set theirs to credit
                $data['PaymentTransaction']['debit'] = 0;//and null out debit cause we arent taking out
                $this->create();//create new record
                if(!$this->save($data, false)) {//save with no validation again
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us a schema dump of your `payment_transactions` table?

Comment: I figured the issue. It the problem actually occured outside of this method call. There was another save that took place which overwrote the last because create() was not called.